# Email Link authentication. How to signUp with a Dynamic Link?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links, password-less

#Flutter Firebase Email-Link Registration with DeepLink#
**My Idea:**
I want so send the user an Email with a `DeepLink/Dynamic Link` which brings them back to my Flutter App where I can `SignUp with Email and Link` and register the Firebase user.

**But:** I can't figure out how to do that. Can't find any Documentations, Tutorials or Examples for this.

This is my Code for now:

```
Future<FirebaseUser> emailLinkLogin(String email, String link) async {
    
    var link = ''; //need to receive a link somewhere?

    try {
      final FirebaseUser user =
          await _auth.signInWithEmailAndLink(email: email, link: link);

      try {
        await _auth.sendSignInWithEmailLink(
          email: email,
          url: 'https://classmateapp-72ce9.firebaseapp.com',
          handleCodeInApp: true,
          iOSBundleID: 'ch.classmate.app',
          androidPackageName: 'ch.classmate.app',
          androidInstallIfNotAvailable: false,
          androidMinimumVersion: '12',
        );
        print('gesendet!');
      } catch (error) {
        print(error);

        await _auth.isSignInWithEmailLink(link);
      }

      updateUserData(user);
      return user;
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Can someone give me a guide to solve my problem?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already set up your Firebase Console, did you?
If that is the case you have to follow the steps on this [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/). It basically says the following:

- Include the [Dynamic Links SDK](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links) in your App
- Create the links programmatically or via the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com)
- Finally handle the request

I would recommend creating the links via the Firebase Console. Examples for step 2 and 3 are shown on the [Dynamic Links SDK](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links) pub page.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, I've already set up my Firebase Console. I get a Deep Link from the Dynamic Link that was sent by email, right? Then I have to check, if the Deep Link is a SignInWithEmailLink and if true I can register the user with email and Deep Link? Is this correct?